# How to make new accounts(object) in Django?

Tags: python, django

```
#views.py

def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           *new_user = Profile.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)*
            login(request, new_user)
            return HttpResponse('signup success.')
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/profile.html', {'form': form})
```

I want to make new accouont(object) so, I want to use User.objects.create_user method

```
#models.py

class Profile(models.Model):
    studentNumber = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    major = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    github = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    sns = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
```

it is my model!
How can I save my model to DB?

Comment: There is no `create_user` for vanilla models, you can create a `Profile` with `form.save()` it will return a `Profile` object.

Comment: thanks !! it works well